# Replacing elements of one table with the elements of another table for common grid

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, data, table

Consider two tables:

```
tab1=Flatten[Table[{i,j,0},{i,0.5,0.7,0.1},{j,0.1,0.3,0.1}],{1,2}];
tab2=Flatten[Table[{i,j,i*j},{i,0.5,0.7,0.2},{j,0.1,0.3,0.2}],{1,2}];
```

These tables have a common subset of the first and second elements of their rows: e.g., `{0.5,0.1}`, and `{0.7,0.3}`. How to make a table from `tab1` where zeros (the third element) in the rows from the common subset are replaced with the corresponding values from `tab2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along these lines might work:

```
tab2Rules = Thread[ReplacePart[3 -> _] /@ tab2 -> tab2];
tab1 /. tab2Rules
```

`{{0.5, 0.1, 0.05}, {0.5, 0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.3, 0.15}, {0.6, 0.1, 0}, {0.6, 0.2, 0}, {0.6, 0.3, 0}, {0.7, 0.1, 0.07}, {0.7, 0.2, 0}, {0.7, 0.3, 0.21}}`

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
tab1 = Flatten[
   Table[{i, j, 0}, {i, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1}, {j, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1}], {1, 2}];
tab2 = Flatten[
   Table[{i, j, i*j}, {i, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2}, {j, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2}], {1, 
    2}];
```

Create rules for a `Lookup`:

```
r1 = Sequence @@@ ({Most@# -> Last@#} & /@ tab2)
```

> {{0.5, 0.1} -> 0.05, {0.5, 0.3} -> 0.15, {0.7, 0.1} ->
> 0.07, {0.7, 0.3} -> 0.21}

```
Sequence @@@ {Most@#, Lookup[r1, {Most@#}, Last@#]} & /@ tab1
```

> {{0.5, 0.1, 0.05}, {0.5, 0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.3, 0.15}, {0.6, 0.1,    0},
> {0.6, 0.2, 0}, {0.6, 0.3, 0}, {0.7, 0.1, 0.07}, {0.7, 0.2,    0},
> {0.7, 0.3, 0.21}}

Answer (score 3):

Using `Association` - overwriting

```
Join @@ Values @ Association[GroupBy[Most] @ tab1, GroupBy[Most] @ tab2]
```

{{0.5, 0.1, 0.05}, {0.5, 0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.3, 0.15}, {0.6, 0.1,
0}, {0.6, 0.2, 0}, {0.6, 0.3, 0}, {0.7, 0.1, 0.07}, {0.7, 0.2,
0}, {0.7, 0.3, 0.21}}

Answer (score 2):

```
Replace[tab1,(MapThread[{#1,#2,0}->{##1}&,Transpose@tab2]),2]

(* {
    {0.5,0.1,0.05},
    {0.5,0.2,0},
    {0.5,0.3,0.15},
    {0.6,0.1,0},
    {0.6,0.2,0},
    {0.6,0.3,0},
    {0.7,0.1,0.07},
    {0.7,0.2,0},
    {0.7,0.3,0.21}
   } *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Values @ AssociationThread[Most /@ #, #] & @ Join[tab1, tab2]
```

> ```
> {{0.5, 0.1, 0.05}, {0.5, 0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.3, 0.15}, {0.6, 0.1, 0},   
>  {0.6, 0.2, 0}, {0.6, 0.3, 0}, {0.7, 0.1, 0.07},   
>  {0.7, 0.2, 0}, {0.7, 0.3, 0.21}}
> ```

Replacements highlighted:

```
% /. a : Alternatives @@ tab2 :> Highlighted[a]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My attempt to do this, defining `ReplaceByCoords`:

```
 ReplaceByCoords[tab1_, tab2_] := 
 Module[{assis, res}, 
 assis[elem_] := 
 Module[{match}, match = SelectFirst[tab2, Most[#] == Most[elem] &];
 If[MissingQ[match], elem, match]]; es = assis /@ tab1; res]
```

Testing `ReplaceByCoords`:

```
res = {{0.5, 0.1, 0.05}, {0.5, 0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.3, 0.15}, {0.6, 0.1, 0}, 
      {0.6, 0.2, 0}, {0.6, 0.3, 0}, {0.7, 0.1, 0.07}, {0.7, 0.2, 0}, 
      {0.7, 0.3, 0.21}};

ReplaceByCoords[tab1, tab2] === res

(*True*)
```